# How do you make a redirect page on Wikipedia?

Tags: links, wikipedia

I have found the article I was looking for on Wikipedia with the message `This article is an orphan.` at the top. I have also found another page with the topic of this article highlighted in red, as if the link should exist but has no target page. The complication is that the term used in the attempted link is not identical to the page title on the article but both are valid and should corefer. How can I make a redirect page whose title is the dead link to solve this problem?

(I hope I explained this clearly enough.)

Comment: Why don't you link to your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this wiki page on redirecting wiki pages: [Help:Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aRedirect).

> A redirect is a page created so that navigation to a given title will
>   take the reader directly to a different page. A redirect is created
>   using the syntax:
>
> `#REDIRECT [[target]]`
>
> where Target is the name of the target page. It is also possible to
>   add a section anchor to make a redirect to a specific section of the
>   target page.
>
> **A page will be treated as a redirect page if its wikitext begins with
>   `#REDIRECT` followed by a valid wikilink or interwikilink.**